# Multiple queries, or nested?

Tags: mysql

I have two channels.

The first channel is 'booking'. This holds the `member_id` and a `tour_id`.

The second channel is 'tours'. This holds the tour details, referenced by the above `tour_id`.

I need to query fields within the 'tours' channel, getting the `tour_id` for those where the query was met. I then need to find all 'booking' entries where the `tour_id` matches one of those were the query was true.

Is it better to complete two SQL queries, or a nested query? If nested, how?

---

**exp_channel_data**
|channel_id|entry_id|field_id_1|...|

**exp_channel_titles**
|channel_id|entry_id|author_id|...|

```
SELECT titles.author_id
FROM exp_channel_data AS tours
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles AS titles ON bookings.entry_id = titles.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data AS bookings
    ON tours.entry_id = bookings.entry_id
    AND bookings.channel_id = '17'
WHERE tours.channel_id = '5'
AND tours.field_id_34 = 'DSV04'
```

---

```
$sql_1 = "
    SELECT entry_id
    FROM exp_channel_data 
    WHERE field_id_34 LIKE 'adas%'
";

$query_1 = ee()->db->query($sql_1);
$test = $query_1->result_array();

$uids = Array();
foreach($test as $u) $uids[] = $u['entry_id'];
$list = implode(",",$uids);


$sql_2 = "
    SELECT ct.author_id
    FROM exp_channel_data AS cd
    LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles AS ct ON cd.entry_id = ct.entry_id 
    WHERE field_id_227 IN ($list)
";

$query_2 = ee()->db->query($sql_2);
$test_2 = $query_2->result_array();
```

Comment: Sample input output required to understand thoroughly.

Comment: channel = table? Sounds like a join to me but sample input/output would make things clear... `SELECT b.member_id FROM tours t LEFT JOIN booking b ON t.tour_id = b.tour_id WHERE t.field1 = 'abc' AND t.field2 = 'def'`

Comment: @hsan Thanks. Both the channels data is in the same table, so I don't think I can use a JOIN. There is a column in the table called 'channel_id' which I can use to target each though.

Comment: @ccdavies wait, so you have booking and tour data in the same table?? This sounds like a really bad idea. And what do you mean by "channel"? Please provide sample data to clarify.

Comment: @hsan Yes. The data is all within a CMS, so I can't choose where it should go. The CMS has channels, which are referenced by their 'channel_id'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a table structure like this:

```
|channel_id|tour_id|member_id|field1|...|
-----------------------------------------
|tours     |1      |NULL     |abc   |   |
|tours     |2      |NULL     |def   |   |
|booking   |1      |1        |      |   |
|booking   |1      |2        |      |   |
|booking   |2      |3        |      |   |
```

You could join the table on itself to get the results you are looking for...

```
SELECT
    booking.tour_id
    booking.member_id
FROM
    my_table tours
    LEFT JOIN my_table booking
        ON tours.tour_id = booking.tour_id
        AND booking.channel_id = 'booking'
WHERE
    tours.channel_id = 'tours'
    AND tours.field1 = 'abc'
```

---

**EDIT as follow-up to the updated question**

I understand that:

- you want to find the *authors* of all *bookings* for all *tours* where `field_id_34` begins with "adas".
- *authors* of bookings are maintained in the table `exp_channel_titles`
- *bookings* and *tours* are maintained in the table `exp_channel_data` and the column `channel_id` is used to differentiate between *bookings* (17) and *tours* (5).
- *bookings* and *tours* are linked by the `entry_id` of a *tour* and the `field_id_227` of a *booking*
- *bookings* and *authors* are linked by the booking's `entry_id` and the `entry_id` in `exp_channel_titles`

So this should give you the list of authors in one query:

```
SELECT
    titles.author_id
FROM
    exp_channel_data tours
    LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data bookings
        ON bookings.channel_id = 17
        AND bookings.field_id_227 = tours.entry_id
    LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles titles
        ON titles.entry_id = bookings.entry_id
WHERE
    tours.channel_id = 5
    AND tours.field_id_34 LIKE 'adas%'
```

Comment: Thank you hsan. I have made an adjustment to the question to show the table columns an how I have used your answer. 
The 'author_id' is in the 'exp_channel_titles' table, so I need to somehow get this author id by the 'entry_id' after I have determind which 'booking' channel entries meet the query. I tried adding an extra LEFT JOIN but this isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: You should switch the joins around. In the join with titles you refer to the bookings table before it is even known in the query.

Comment: I haven't been able to work out this with your example. Please see the edit to my question with a working example with two queries. Perhaps this will help explain what I am trying to do?